# My BHO does not work properly. DocumentComplete does not trigger

Tags: visual-c++, bho

I am doing a BHO for Internet Explorer. The problem is only the SetSite is working. BUt the DocumentComplete does not been triggered. I need some help in pointing me what is I am doing wrong.

Here is what I declared inside my header file:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CStockBar : 
public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
public CComCoClass<CStockBar, &CLSID_StockBar>,
public IDeskBand,
public IObjectWithSite,
public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CStockBar>,
public IInputObject, 
public IDispatchImpl<IStockBar, &IID_IStockBar, &LIBID_MOTLEYFOOLLib>,
public IDispEventImpl<1, CStockBar, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>
{
public:
CStockBar();

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_STOCKBAR)
DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

BEGIN_CATEGORY_MAP(CStockBar)
//  IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY(CATID_InfoBand)
//  IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY(CATID_CommBand)
//  IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY(CATID_DeskBand)
END_CATEGORY_MAP()

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CStockBar)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IStockBar)
//  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IInputObject)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleWindow)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(IID_IDockingWindow, IDockingWindow)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectWithSite)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(IID_IDeskBand, IDeskBand)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
END_COM_MAP()

BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CStockBar)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)
END_SINK_MAP()
```

Here is my SetSite and DocumentComplete functions:

```
   STDMETHODIMP CStockBar::SetSite(IUnknown* pUnkSite)
   {
    //If a site is being held, release it.
if(m_pSite)
{
    m_ReflectWnd.GetToolBar().SetBrowser(NULL);
    m_pSite->Release();
    m_pSite = NULL;
}
    if (pUnkSite != NULL)
   {
    // Cache the pointer to IWebBrowser2.
   HRESULT hr = pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&m_spWebBrowser);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Register to sink events from DWebBrowserEvents2.
        hr = DispEventAdvise(m_spWebBrowser);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            m_fAdvised = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
else
{
  if (m_fAdvised)
    {
        DispEventUnadvise(m_spWebBrowser);
        m_fAdvised = FALSE;
    }
    m_spWebBrowser.Release();
}
//If punkSite is not NULL, a new site is being set.
if(pUnkSite)
{
    //Get the parent window.
    IOleWindow  *pOleWindow = NULL;

    m_hWndParent = NULL;

    if(SUCCEEDED(pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (LPVOID*)&pOleWindow)))
    {
        pOleWindow->GetWindow(&m_hWndParent);
        pOleWindow->Release();
    }

    if(!::IsWindow(m_hWndParent))
        return E_FAIL;

    if(!RegisterAndCreateWindow())
        return E_FAIL;

    //Get and keep the IInputObjectSite pointer.
    if(FAILED(pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IInputObjectSite, (LPVOID*)&m_pSite)))
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }  

    IWebBrowser2* s_pFrameWB = NULL;
    IOleCommandTarget* pCmdTarget = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget, (LPVOID*)&pCmdTarget);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IServiceProvider* pSP;
        hr = pCmdTarget->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (LPVOID*)&pSP);

        pCmdTarget->Release();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pSP->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2, (LPVOID*)&s_pFrameWB);
            pSP->Release();
            _ASSERT(s_pFrameWB);
            m_ReflectWnd.GetToolBar().SetBrowser(s_pFrameWB);
            s_pFrameWB->Release();
        }
    }
 }
return S_OK;
   }




  void STDMETHODCALLTYPE CStockBar::OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL)
 {
   // Retrieve the top-level window from the site.
   HWND hwnd;
   HRESULT hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_HWND((LONG_PTR*)&hwnd);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
    // Output a message box when page is loaded.
    MessageBox(hwnd,"Hello World!","BHO", MB_OK);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use SINK_ENTRY_INFO with IDispEventImpl as pointed in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wt7d0s4(v=vs.80).aspx

You are probably running your code in release as otherwise you would have get a assertion because idispeventimpl wouldn't be able to retrieve the typelib for DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2. DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2 doesn't have a typelib because it's a disp interface.

Declare in your header:

```
extern ATL::_ATL_FUNC_INFO DocumentComplete2Struct;

BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CStockBar)
    SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1, __uuidof(DWebBrowserEvents2), DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete, &DocumentComplete2Struct);
END_SINK_MAP()
```

In your CPP :

```
ATL::_ATL_FUNC_INFO DocumentComplete2Struct = {CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 2, {VT_DISPATCH, VT_BYREF|VT_VARIANT}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything that stands out as definably incorrect, so here is another example hacked out of some working code, includes only the bits needed for site to keep it simple.

One thing that may be an issue is - `m_spWebBrowser` if this is the ATL class then it doesn't like you overwriting existing using the address of once it is set.  It may be returning false at which point you won't be running advise.
    HRESULT hr = pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&m_spWebBrowser);

declaration h

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CStockBar: 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComGlobalsThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CStockBar, &CLSID_StockBar>, 
    public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CStockBar>,
    public IDispEventImpl<1, CStockBar, &__uuidof(DWebBrowserEvents2), &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 0>{

protected:
    typedef IDispEventImpl<1, CStockBar, &__uuidof(DWebBrowserEvents2), &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 0> base_BrowserDispEvents;
    typedef IObjectWithSiteImpl<CStockBar> base_objectWithSite;

BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CStockBar)
// we use this variation - think it resolves the same
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, (__uuidof(DWebBrowserEvents2)), DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete) 
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)
END_SINK_MAP()

CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> m_spBrowser;
```

Implementation cpp

```
STDMETHODIMP CStockBar::SetSite(IUnknown* pUnkSite) {

    // Detach the web browser and site
    if (m_spBrowser) {
        base_BrowserDispEvents::DispEventUnadvise(m_spBrowser);
        m_spBrowser.Release();
    }

    if (pUnkSite) {

        m_spBrowser = pUnkSite;
        if (m_spBrowser)
        {
            base_BrowserDispEvents::DispEventAdvise(m_spBrowser);
        }

    }

    return base_objectWithSite::SetSite(pUnkSite);
```